# How Display Presentation of PowerPoint inside WPF C# application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, powerpoint

I have an app that displays some PowerPoint files for users that can't interact with it,
so after some googling, I found some solutions but they didn't convince me.

1. I found some users use syncfusion package but I found it paid
2. The second solution is using WebView but I can't move the slides programmatically
3. Run Microsoft PowerPoint inside my app but I can't control the slides and remove the toolbar
4. I found DocumentFormat.OpenXml Object to read pptx files but I can't display it (I did'n find how!)

so there is another solution should I try that fits my situation!

Comment: What about just running Microsoft PowerPoint outside your app?

Comment: I need to run it without a toolbar and in a specific position and control the time of slides

Comment: you're not really going to find what you're looking for. Export slides to PNG or SVG and build a toolbar that navigates these "slides" for you in WPF.